# SCM-Server and Apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, svn, mod-proxy, scmmanager

I try to hide the SCM-Manager behind Apache 2.4.

The Apache is listening on

```
http://192.168.2.102
```

and the SCM is listening on

```
http://192.168.2.102:8080
```

Following [this](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/apache/apache-mod_proxy) description I am able to access the management interface of SCM server through Apache. With this **mod_proxy** configuration

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.2.102:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    <Location /scm>
        ProxyPass http://192.168.2.102:8080/scm connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.2.102:8080/scm
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can also check out my repository.

By adding this **mod_rewrite** rule

```
RewriteRule ^/svn/(.*)$ /scm/svn/$1 [P]
```

my intention was to permit the access to my repo via

```
http://192.168.2.102/svn/REPO
```

But at check out with

```
svn co http://192.168.2.102/svn/aaa aaa
```

I get this error:

```
svn: E175002: svn: E175002: E175002: Invalid URL 'http://192.168.2.102:8080/svn/aaa' requested
```

What else should I set for the rewrite module to serve me the repo just with the **/svn/REPO** URI?

SK

Comment: Please have a look at this issue: https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/issues/652/scm-tomcat-apache-mod_proxy